# Can I give my rats bits of Christmas tree to chew?

Tags: diet, rodents, rat

Is it safe to give my rats branches cut off disposed Christmas trees?

There's a huge pile outside my apartment.

Comment: Are you asking about a Tree that was in your house, or one that is laying out on the street, that belonged to someone else? If it is your tree, what if any additives did you put in the water?

Comment: Ones disposed of, there's a huge pile outside my apartment blog waiting for collection.  Are there common, harmful additives in Christmas tree water?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No,

Pine and Cedar are generally considered toxic to Rats (*and many small mammals*) [pine should not be used as bedding](http://www.ratfanclub.org/litters.html) by extension they should not be offered as chew toys.

There are several home remedies [(*most don't work*)](http://mythbustersresults.com/special10) for keeping needles on trees, and you have no idea what methods may have been used on the trees that have been disposed of.

In fact [many woods can be harmful for a rat to chew on](https://web.archive.org/web/20150214145016/http://animals.pawnation.com/woods-bad-rats-chew-6223.html), so making healthy choices on behalf of your rat is important. (*still looking for a really good reliable reference, on best rat wood chews*)

Comment: Thanks, just followed that link.  With so many toxic woods around, it's amazing there are any rats alive in the wild!